# Perforce: restoring a branch to an old changelist and then restoring it to the current state

Tags: perforce, restore, rollback

I want to restore my branch to a given changelist to generate certain executables and then restore it back to the original state. An example will make this clear.

Currently the last changelist that went into main is `@108`.
I want main restored to changelist `@100`. 
So if anyone syncs, they will see the changes upto `@100`.
So the Engineering team can generate the executables out of `@100` by just doing a `p4 sync`.

I have to do this since the engineering team won't do:

```
% p4 sync @100
```

due to process requirements.

Once this is done, I need to restore all the changelists from `@101` to `@108`by the end of the day so that the nightly builds don't get affected.

Is there a graphical way using `p4v` to do this? If there are pointers to command line options it would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click on a folder in P4V, you can choose "Rollback..." and pick 100 as the changelist you want to roll back to.

Then at the end of the day, you would repeat that process and pick 108.

That should leave everything as it was at the beginning of the day. It should work fine as long as no one will be checking in during this process.

Answer (score 2):

As Mike said, doing "Rollback..." in P4V should let you reset everything to a particular changelist.

I'll chip in the command line version as well.  From the "main" root directory:

```
p4 copy ...@100 ...
p4 submit
```

This is a slightly atypical use of "p4 copy", but it turns out that just copying an old version of a directory on top of itself is a very effective and clean way of rolling back.  You can use the "-v" option on "p4 copy" to skip having to sync everything to your workspace.

Comment: Had to pick one. I tried Mike's one first and it worked. So marking it as an answer.